# Compartilhar LocalStorage com browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, localstorage

Existe alguma forma de compartilhar localstorage com vários browsers?
Por exemplo, eu defino `localStorage.setItem("lang", "pt");` no Chrome, porém, gostaria que esse valor ficasse disponível no Firefox e outros navegadores que dêem suporte a LocalStorage.

OBJETIVO:
Meu objetivo com isso é fazer uma forma do meu sistema entender a língua que o cliente escolher e que eu salvei no localstorage e recuperar em outros momentos, em outros navegadores.

Existe alguma forma?

Comment: Se fosse possivel, seria uma falha de segurança bem grave.

Comment: vou editar a pergunta pra ver se surge alguma sugestão bacana...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível, pois o `localStorage` é uma implementação de uma especificação do  HTML5, cada navegador implementa da forma que quer e também a localização desses dados muda de um navegador para o outro.

O que pode ser feito é você salvar essa informações no servidor e "setar" os valores no `localStorage` de cada navegador que o usuário acessar.

*Referência:* [html5 Local Storage Across Different Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795496/5314295)